# flask threading on triggering a different process

Tags: python, multithreading, web, flask

In route request in Flask, how do I trigger a thread to start and have it continue right away to the next line. In the code below, how do I get the print "Onto the next already" to occur right after the new thread is spawned, rather than wait the ~10 sec for it to finish?

Thanks!

```
def consumer(searchValue,assignedUniqueID):
    print "Searching..."
    print "Running thread! Args:", (searchValue, assignedUniqueID)
    time.sleep(10)
    print "Done!"

@app.route('/_search')
def add_numbers():
    assignedUniqueID = str(uuid.uuid4())
    Thread(target=consumer(searchValue,assignedUniqueID)).start()
    print "Onto the next already"
    return jsonify(result="33434443",
                       assignedUniqueID = assignedUniqueID
               )
```

Comment: aside from the unresolved `searchValue` name you're passing around without defining in your example, this code looks like it should do what you're asking for.  Can you post a little more information?  Do you get an error?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this is more a comment than an answer, I'm posting here because it is a bit large for the comment system.

This kind of bug can be hard to track in Flask given their extensive use of [thread-local storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) and [other magic](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/design/#thread-locals).

In web applications multitasking is often handled by the use of queues instead of threads, with the web application queing tasks and background daemons (workers) doing the job. This approach scales a lot better:

- workers can live in other machines
- the number of workers running in parallel is easier to control than the number of running threads. I've seen even small traffic surges bringing a server to a halt when using threads.
- it is easier to synchronize and or handle concurrency

Specially popular are solutions involving [AMQP](http://www.amqp.org/) or Key/Value databases like [redis](http://redis.io/) or [memcached](http://memcached.org/). For AMQP in Python, take a look at [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/), I use it a lot in combination with Django.